# System preference Scrollbar Show Always on OSx

Tags: macos, scroll, scrollbar, hide

I have a website and i want to hide scrollbars i did the css and everything but if you are in a osx computer and you have in your preference show always scrollbars you see them is there any way you can hide them?? you know within the computer preference of showing it.. i need to hide the scrollbars is there any way you can do it with jquery or php or css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create two divs: one with overflow:hidden and the inner one with position:absolute. And all scrolling via js/JQuery. I did such thing about 5 years ago when I was implementing custom scroll bars.